# How to make both toState and fromState append option as a Child

Tags: javascript, arrays, appendchild

toState appends and fromState are supposed to append option as a child, but currently it's only the State that comes lasts that appends. if fromState comes last it appends options as a child but toState doesn't append option and vice versa

```
  response.json().then(function (data) {
    // Get States ID of to and from
    let toState = document.getElementById('to-state');
    let fromState = document.getElementById('from-state');

    for (let i = 0; i < data.states.length; i++) {

      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = data.states[i].name;
      option.value = data.states[i].id;
      toState.appendChild(option)
      fromState.appendChild(option)

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position

> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously.

So the second time you call `appendChild()` the node is moved from its previous parent to a new parent, that is from `to-state` to `from-state` or viceversa. In order to append the same child node to both parent nodes you need to clone it:

```
toState.appendChild(option);
fromState.appendChild(option.cloneNode(true));
```

The parameter `true` tells `cloneNode()` to make a full copy of its subtree.